# Stripe webhooks when subscription charge fails with Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, stripe-payments, webhooks, subscription, amazon-cognito

I would love to get an idea of canceling subscription if Stripe subscription charge fails with webhooks(unless there's better way to do it).

Here is what I'm thinking.

1. Stripe subscription fails to charge customer
2. Stripe webhooks make a request to API with `invoice.payment_failed`
3. API triggers a Lambda function
4. Lambda function removes Cognito `custom:stripesubid` attribute and user group

Does it work? I would love to see some sample code if available.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't help with the Lambda stuff, but Stripe can automatically cancel subscriptions after too many failed payments, depending on how you configure your subscription settings: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/recurring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) from Stripe. Here is a good tutorial of how to do exactly what you are needing: https://www.truespotmedia.com/testing-webhooks-in-stripe-with-php/